# dataTable Selectable Events

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I have a data table set up such that `selectionMode="multiple"`and I wind up with a column for checkboxes. I have 2 ajax events keying off of rowSelectCheckbox and rowUnselectCheckbox that fire off whenever any of the checkboxes are toggled on or off. My problem is that these ajax events are not firing off for the unique checkbox in the header that selects/unselects all other checkboxes in mass. Is there a way I can disable this checkbox or is there a different event I can tell ajax to look for?

Comment: PrimeFaces 0.9 is not supported anymore. Use PrimeFaces 11.6. And read [ask] and act accordingly (the mcve part). And check the PF documentation

Comment: Primefaces 5.2 is the current stable release and I'm using that... I have no idea where you are getting 0.9 or 11.6 from

Comment: You nowhere posted what you used so I 'guessed'. But thanks for at least making this part clear. Now the other things